# How do I create webapps in elementaryOS?

Tags: epiphany, gnome

I'd like to add O365 shortcuts to my dock. I can do this in Chrome but it just opens regular chrome. I'm sure I was previously able to open a contained webapp once upon a time without the location bar and other "general" web browsing stuff.

Answer (score 2):

It's no longer supported since Elementary switched from a system Epiphany to a flatpak version of Epiphany, which has never supported web apps. Sorry.

There is good news: there is some work in progress to add web app support for the flatpaked Epiphany. So it should hopefully be possible again in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yet another reason web support isn't where it needs to be on eOS. I guess I'll switch to chrome...again.

Answer (score 0):

I just remove flatpack version of epiphany:

```
flatpak remove epiphany
```

and install the repository version with:

```
apt install epiphany-browser
```

Now I have again web apps. Also my gtk theme is now recognized, that is a big plus :)

Thanks to @MichaelC answer, I now understand why some apps don't take my personal gtk theme.

Answer (score 0):

If the flatpak application does not apply your theme, you can create a ".themes" folder in the "home" folder. Move your theme there)

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not in AppCenter anymore, [Webpin](https://github.com/artemanufrij/webpin) can still be installed in elementaryOS 6.1 (and mostly likely 7.x, too), using [the build instructions](https://github.com/artemanufrij/webpin#install-from-github) from the GitHub project page.

You will probably want to install `elementary-sdk` from the system package manager, so that you're sure to have all the build toolchain stuff you need to build it from source.

I myself use Webpin to wrap Google Calendar, Outlook mail, and a half-dozen other sites and services, and it works fine. As someone who has used Fluid.app on macOS for years, and has tried every "site-specific browser" option on Linux since [Prism](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Prism), I'm happy to say Webpin is one that pretty much gets it right.

The only downside is it (currently) lacks the ability to clear cookies and other site-specific storage on demand, and its cookie store is shared among all instances. This means that you can't, for example, have personal and uni/work Outlook accounts pinned as separate apps.